# Bibliography customization, year as bib label

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm hoping to arrive at a simple bibliography customization where the year appears as the bib label.

Firstly, I consider that the solution could come from creating a `.bst` file, re-defining the biblabel or a combination of the latter (or maybe something simple I'm overlooking).

I typically use biblatex with biber as a backend.

*Desired functionality*

The following refers to the formatting of the entries made by `\printbibliography`.  I'm not concerned here with citation style because `\nocite{*}` is used.

As background, consider a collection .bib items which are less like article citations, instead the content is predominantly limited to title, note, and sometimes month fields.

I would essentially like to replace the biblabel with the year from the bib entry.  The body of the bib entry could follow the same logical sequence of a popular style with few exceptions.  The year is not needed in the body of the bib entry.

Implementation of this may also require having a generous indent of the body of the bib entry; four characters for the year and then some.  All body lines would have the same indent.  The bib label text and the first line would be on the same line.

The option to make the biblabel some assembly of the month and year (e.g. `<month>, <year>`) also has a likely use case.  One might also want to specify the indentation of the body on the fly if one jumped from having the year as bib label versus month + year as biblabel between different refsections.

*How might this work?*

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380299/change-position-of-year-field-in-authoryear-biblatex-style) explains how to change the position of the year.  Perhaps it could shed light on how to remove it?

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348126/creating-a-bibliography-with-fixed-indention-and-authoryear-labels-using-biblate) describes the authoryear style for biblatex.  Perhaps a year style is already possible?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Throwing together code for `mergedate` and poking about with local and global labeldate settings we arrive at

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[labeldateparts, locallabelwidth]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldatewidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labeldatewidth]{\printlabeldate}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labeldatewidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iflabeldateisdate}
    and
    not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
  }
    {}
    {\printdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iflabeldateisdate}
    and
    not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printdate}}%
  \newunit}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\labeldatewidth}
\newlength{\locallabeldatewidth}

\appto\abx@dolabelwidths{\do{labeldate}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \nottoggle{blx@skipbib}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@getlabeldata
     \blx@setlabwidth{\labeldatewidth}{%
       \printtext[labeldatewidth]{\printlabeldate}}%
     \endgroup}
    {}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \blx@setlabwidth{\locallabeldatewidth}{%
     \printtext[labeldatewidth]{\printlabeldate}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\changedateformat}[2]{%
  \csdef{blx@dateformat@#1date}{#2}%
  \protected\csdef{blx@imc@print#1date}{\csuse{mkdaterange#2}{#1}}%
  \protected\csdef{blx@imc@print#1dateextra}{\csuse{mkdaterange#2extra}{#1}}}
\makeatletter



\begin{document}

\nocite{sigfridsson, worman, knuth:ct:a, knuth:ct:b, knuth:ct:c, nussbaum, vizedom:related, baez/online, itzhaki, markey, wassenberg}

\printbibliography

\changedateformat{label}{long}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliographies with different date-based indentations]

*edit* Updated to work with `biblatex` v3.16. For older versions of `biblatex` refer to the edit history.

Comment: moewe, as to the deleted answer, I left a message there, but I suppose you didn't get it before I deleted. I said then I hadn't forgotten the date parentheses, but was just offering a general idea. But, still, as I wouldn't have much time today to see it through and as you had provided a more thorough solution I'd leave that one be. Even though in principle the answer could be kept in those (partial) terms, I do think your answer is superior and sort of encompasses what I had proposed, so I saw no reason to keep it. No grudges here, on the contrary, thank you for the pointer on `mergedate`.

Comment: @gusbrs Still I would ask you to (re)consider undeleting your answer. As I said, the idea is actually quite clever. It is more accessible and uses fewer internal macros than mine, so in that respect your answer is better.

Comment: Ok! I guess if simplicity is a criterion, there's something there then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is possible to adapt the `alphabetic` style to use the year as `labelalpha`. Proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: If you'd also like to remove the year from the references in cases in which the date is comprised only of the year, you can go with (courtesy of moewe):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{month}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{season}}
        }
    {}
    {\printdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{month}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{season}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
        }
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printdate}}%
     \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want to do something about the empty issue-date parentheses for `@article`s. The easiest way is probably a check similar to those done for `mergedate`.

Comment: @moewe, I didn't forget about it, I just offered a general idea. But, as I'll have little time for this today and as you offered something more thorough, I'll probably leave this one be.

Comment: I think you only need something along the lines of `\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{season}}
  }
    {}
    {\printdate}}` (modulo line breaks)

Comment: and `\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    \iffieldundef{year}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{season}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printdate}}%
  \newunit}`. But you need to drop the `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{year}}`.

Comment: That will cause the year to reappear if there is a more precise date, i.e. (March 1999) instead of only (March). But the latter would need more fiddling.

Comment: @moewe, thank you very much. I'll see to it as soon as I can.

Comment: @moewe, I tested your suggestions and I'm afraid I did not quite grasp what you intended with them. The year was actually kept, even in the absence of other date parts. Anyway, I opted for the strong point of the answer and kept things simple. The OP states the year is "not needed" but does not actually require that the year be actually removed, and is quite vague in general regarding the style of the entries. So perhaps sticking to defaults is a good idea in this case. (But please let me know if you think this is not a good approach somehow).

Comment: Ah yes, I made a stupid mistake. The two `\iffieldundef{year}`s should have been `\iffieldundef{month}`. I messed up a few other things as well, so here they are again `\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{month}} and test {\iffieldundef{season}}}
    {}
    {\printdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
 \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{month}} and test {\iffieldundef{season}} and test {\iffieldundef{issue}}} 
   {}
   {\printtext[parens]{%
      \printfield{issue}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printdate}}%
   \newunit}`

Comment: Ah! now I do get it. Thank you! (answer updated).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the wrong code.