# Can one have year as bib labels for biblatex publist with plnumbered=false option?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I'm using publist and would like to have lists of publications not numbered but formatted as in this question: [Bibliography customization, year as bib label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419702/bibliography-customization-year-as-bib-label). MWE using publist is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=publist,boldyear=false,plnumbered=false,backend=biber,labeldateparts=false]{biblatex}
\plauthorname[Gary]{Westfahl}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}    
\begin{document}   
\nocite{*}   
\printbibliography[filter=mine]    
\end{document}
```

yielding this result:
[image]
I'd like to have this
[image]
which is produced using the answer by gusbrs, based on the alphabetic style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{month}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{season}}
        }
    {}
    {\printdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{month}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{season}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
        }
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printdate}}%
     \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{#1}

\begin{document}

\nocite{westfahl:space,westfahl:frontier}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But I can't see how to transpose it to publist. Nor, alas, do I see how to port moewe's answer.

Thanks to moewe for his revised code on [Bibliography customization, year as bib label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419702/bibliography-customization-year-as-bib-label); it now works perfectly!

But his answer to *this* question is just a tad short of fully working for my purposes.

One weird thing, changing the answer MWE to `\nocite{*}` and running with latexmk I get an error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempb.
<to be read again> 
                   \crcr 
l.327     \endentry?
```

Letting latexmk run, the result has some entries run together. For example, wassenberg, herrmann & yoon appear together with year 2010.

Now, since as shown in the screenshot above I'd like no (round brackets) around the date I changed to `\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldatewidth}{#1}`. I tried the author command `\plauthorname[Gary]{Westfahl}` together with `\printbibliography[filter=mine]`, again with `\nocite{*}`, with almost perfect results, except for an extra space, or “, ed.” for collections edited by only the cv author, right before the entry. Of course `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{}` introduces the problem of omitting the needed space after publist's “(Some Coeditor).”

Comment: Thanks for the hint that my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419702/35864 was outdated. I fixed it and it should work with current versions of `biblatex` again. In principle the answer also works with `biblatex-publist`, but you get quite some date duplication in the output. So some additional tweaks are necessary. I shall have a look at that.

Comment: I get similar errors without my code in a simple document with just `style=publist,`, so this appears to be a style issue: https://gist.github.com/moewew/fc54715919a729699cbce0f94f1b1ef2. I think the minimal problematic entries are https://gist.github.com/moewew/eb8ab18b3d1e913171313a9d6be39a83. Report it to the `biblatex-publist` maintainer at https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/issues.

Comment: `herrmann,aksin,yoon` are run together because they are declared as a `@set`. Sets don't really have a labeldate either, so that explains why there is no date there. Probably nothing you have to worry about in your real-world document either.

Answer (score 1):

My fixed answer (thanks for the hint) to [Bibliography customization, year as bib label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419702/35864) is in principle also applicable to `biblatex-publist`, but it needs some slight modifications for the different macro names and calls of `biblatex-publist`. In particular `biblatex-publist` prints the date in `bpl:year+labelyear`, so we need to modify that bibmacro as well.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=publist]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldatewidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\makeatletter
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labeldatewidth]{\printlabeldate}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labeldatewidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\renewbibmacro*{bpl:year+labelyear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}{%
        \iffieldundef{pubstate}%
            {\let\bbx@lasthash\undefined}%
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:date:labeldate+extradate}%
             \savefield{pubstate}{\bbx@lasthash}%
             \clearfield{pubstate}%
            }%
    }{%
           \ifboolexpr{
             test {\iflabeldateisdate}
             and
             not test {\ifdateshavedifferentprecision{label}{}}
           }
           {\printunit{}}
           {\usebibmacro{bpl:date:labeldate+extradate}}%
         \savefield{year}{\bbx@lasthash}%
         \clearfield{year}%
    }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \if@hlauthor
        \ifnameundef{author}
            {}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \iffieldundef{nameaddon}
                 {}
                 {%
                  \mkbibbrackets{%
                      \bibstring{alias}%
                      \addspace\printfield{nameaddon}%
                  }%
                 }%
            }%
        \adddot\addspace\usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
    \else% \if@hlauthor false
        \ifnameundef{author}
            {}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}\setunit{\addspace}%
             \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \iffieldundef{nameaddon}
                 {}
                 {%
                  \mkbibbrackets{%
                      \bibstring{alias}%
                      \addspace\printfield{nameaddon}%
                  }%
                 }%
            }%
    \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
    \if@hlauthor
        \ifnameundef{editor}
            {}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
             \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
             \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
            }%
            \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
            \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
            \clearname{editor}%
    \else% \if@hlauthor false
        \ifnameundef{editor}
            {}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
             \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
             \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
             \clearname{editor}%
            }%
    \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}

\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
    \if@hlauthor
        \ifboolexpr{
            test \ifuseeditor
            and not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
             \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
             \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
             \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
             \clearname{editor}%
            }
            {}%
    \else% \if@hlauthor false
        \ifboolexpr{
            test \ifuseeditor
            and not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
             \setunit{\addspace}%
             \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
             \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
             \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
             \clearname{editor}%
            }
            {}%
    \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}


\newlength{\labeldatewidth}
\newlength{\locallabeldatewidth}

\appto\abx@dolabelwidths{\do{labeldate}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \nottoggle{blx@skipbib}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@getlabeldata
     \blx@setlabwidth{\labeldatewidth}{%
       \printtext[labeldatewidth]{\printlabeldate}}%
     \endgroup}
    {}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \blx@setlabwidth{\locallabeldatewidth}{%
     \printtext[labeldatewidth]{\printlabeldate}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\changedateformat}[2]{%
  \csdef{blx@dateformat@#1date}{#2}%
  \protected\csdef{blx@imc@print#1date}{\csuse{mkdaterange#2}{#1}}%
  \protected\csdef{blx@imc@print#1dateextra}{\csuse{mkdaterange#2extra}{#1}}}
\makeatletter



\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with date on the left in list margin.]

Comment: There seems to be still some conflict with publist. Not sure how exactly to report the issues, there isn't space here in a comment, so I'm editing the question.

Comment: Great, all working now.  I'll report the issue to the publist maintainer.  Many thanks, @moewe, again and as always!